# Separar pequenas strings de uma string gigante

Tags: c, string

Olá. Tenho que fazer uma função para ler uma string enorme e depois dividi-la em pequenas strings para cada campo. Cada campo seria separado por `;` exemplo:

```
BRUNNY;PR;MG;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;260;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5260;3215-2260;08;21;dep.brunny@camara.leg.br;BRUNNY;Exma. Senhora Deputada;BRUNIELE FERREIRA GOMES
```

O que eu pensei até então foi:

```
int i,a = 0; char str[1000];
scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
   if (str[i] == ';')
   {
    /** Essa parte eu não consegui pensar em como transferir a palavra encontrada para a sua variável. */
    a = i + 1;
   }
}
```

Não encontrei uma maneira de passar cada palavra para a sua variável, visto que elas seriam assim: nome, partido, uf, endereço ....

Answer (score 2):

A solução mais simples seria mesmo utilizando a função [`strtok` da biblioteca de c](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), que permite ler palavra a palavra com base num separador.

A minha resposta é em tudo semelhante à que consta na documentação à exceção que criei um array de strings para guardar os vários valores encontrados.
Seria obviamente inviável guardar os vários valores em variáveis soltas.

Código:

```
int i = 0;
char str[1000];
scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

//primeiro achar a quantidade de separadores para criar o array com o tamanho certo
char *letra = str;
int separadores = 0;

while (*letra != '\0'){
    if (*(letra++) == ';') separadores++;
}

char* palavras[separadores]; //criar o array de palavras interpretadas
char *palavra = strtok(str, ";"); //achar a primeira palavra com strtok

while (palavra != NULL){ //se já chegou ao fim devolve NULL
    palavras[i++] = palavra; //guardar a palavra corrente e avançar
    palavra = strtok(NULL, ";"); //achar a próxima palavra
}
```

Note na chamada particular que é feita para achar a segunda e subsequentes palavras:

```
palavra = strtok(NULL, ";");
```

Que recebe o valor `NULL`. Isto faz com que o `strtok` continue na ultima palavra que tinha sido pesquisada, tal como indica na documentação:

> Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the
>   function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the
>   function ended.

É relevante também indicar que o `strtok` altera a string original, por isso se for necessário utiliza-la mais á frente no código convém fazer uma copia da mesma antes de achar as palavras. A função mais indicada para isso seria o `strcpy`:

```
char str[1000];
char strOriginal[1000]; 
strcpy(strOriginal, str); //copiar de str para strOriginal
//resto do código
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/jUMG0W)

Comment: Se interessar manter o estado original de `str`, basta fazer uma cópia usando `strcpy` para uma outra variável e usar `str` para tokenizar.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim não falei sobre isso mas sim é relevante indicar que o `strtok` altera de facto a string original. Obrigado por relembrar

Comment: alguns traumas de faculdade que eu desejo que outras pessoas não passem :) Afinal, não é todo mundo que lembra de RTFM.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Concordo plenamente. O c está cheio de pormenores pequenos que acabam dando dores de cabeça e consumindo tempo quando não se sabe deles.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que você utilize a função `strtok()` para extrair os tokens contidos na linha e as funções `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `strdup()` e `free()` para alocar uma lista de strings completamente dinâmica.

Segue um exemplo (testado) da ideia proposta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char ** strsplit( const char * src, const char * delim )
{
    char * pbuf = NULL;
    char * ptok = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int srclen = 0;
    char ** pparr = NULL;

    srclen = strlen( src );

    pbuf = (char*) malloc( srclen + 1 );

    if( !pbuf )
        return NULL;

    strcpy( pbuf, src );

    ptok = strtok( pbuf, delim );

    while( ptok )
    {
        pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
        *(pparr + count) = strdup(ptok);

        count++;
        ptok = strtok( NULL, delim );
    }

    pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
    *(pparr + count) = NULL;

    free(pbuf);

    return pparr;
}


void strsplitfree( char ** strlist )
{
    int i = 0;

    while( strlist[i])
        free( strlist[i++] );

    free( strlist );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    char ** pp = NULL;

    pp = strsplit( argv[1], ";" );

    while( pp[i] )
    {
        printf("[%d] %s\n", i + 1, pp[i] );
        i++;
    }

    strsplitfree( pp );

    return 0;
}
```

Teste #1:

```
$ ./split "Alpha;Beta;Gamma;Delta;Epsilon"
[1] Alpha
[2] Beta
[3] Gamma
[4] Delta
[5] Epsilon
```

Teste #2:

```
$ ./split "Nome;Sexo;Data de Nascimento;Cidade de Nascimento;Estado Civil"
[1] Nome
[2] Sexo
[3] Data de Nascimento
[4] Cidade de Nascimento
[5] Estado Civil
```

Teste #3:

```
$ ./split "BRUNNY;PR;MG;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;260;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5260;3215-2260;08;21;dep.brunny@camara.leg.br;BRUNNY;Exma. Senhora Deputada;BRUNIELE FERREIRA GOMES"
[1] BRUNNY
[2] PR
[3] MG
[4] T
[5] Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo
[6] 4
[7] , gabinete nº
[8] 260
[9] Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900
[10] 3215-5260
[11] 3215-2260
[12] 08
[13] 21
[14] dep.brunny@camara.leg.br
[15] BRUNNY
[16] Exma. Senhora Deputada
[17] BRUNIELE FERREIRA GOMES
```