# Problemas na leitura de Arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Semana passada fiz uma [pergunta sobre como ler uma string "gigante"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236817/64969). Graças a ajuda do pessoal daqui consegui implementar a função.

Agora, cheguei a um novo problema. A leitura do arquivo não está sendo executada corretamente. O programa não está lendo até o fim do arquivo.

Está sempre imprimindo a primeira linha e ainda de forma incompleta.

O arquivo contém 514 linhas com as entradas nesse estilo:

```
ALEX CANZIANI;PTB;PR;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;842;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5842;3215-2842;06;11;dep.alexcanziani@camara.leg.br;ALEX CANZIANI;Exmo. Senhor Deputado;Registrador de Imóveis;ALEX CANZIANI SILVEIRA
...
ALEX MANENTE;PPS;SP;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;245;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5245;3215-2245;08;22;dep.alexmanente@camara.leg.br;ALEX MANENTE;Exmo. Senhor Deputado;Bacharel  Em Direito;ALEX SPINELLI MANENTE
```

Struct:

```
struct padrao{
    char nomeparlamentar[50];
    char partido[12];
    char UF[3];
    char estado[2];
    char endereco[50];
    char anexo[3];
    char Econt[50];
    char gabinete[5];
    char Ecompl[50];
    char telefone[12];
    char fax[12];
    char mesniver[3];
    char dianiver[3];
    char email[30];
    char nomesacento[50];
    char tratamento[50];
    char profissao[20];
    char nomecivil[70];
};
typedef struct padrao Cadastro;
Cadastro ladrao[MAX];
```

Função que faz a leitura do arquivo:

```
void RecebeDados(Cadastro ladrao){
    FILE *fp = fopen("ListadeDeputados1.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado.");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i=0;
    char str[1000];
    fscanf(fp, " %[^\n]s", str);

    char* palavras[18];
    char *palavra = strtok(str, ";");

    while (palavra != NULL)
    {
        palavras[i++] = palavra;
        palavra = strtok(NULL, ";");
        printf("%s\n", palavra);
    }
    strcpy(ladrao.nomeparlamentar,&palavra[0]);
    strcpy(ladrao.partido,&palavra[1]);
    strcpy(ladrao.UF,&palavra[2]);
    strcpy(ladrao.estado,&palavra[3]);
    strcpy(ladrao.endereco,&palavra[4]);
    strcpy(ladrao.anexo,&palavra[5]);
    strcpy(ladrao.Econt,&palavra[6]);
    strcpy(ladrao.gabinete,&palavra[7]);
    strcpy(ladrao.Ecompl,&palavra[8]);
    strcpy(ladrao.telefone,&palavra[9]);
    strcpy(ladrao.fax,&palavra[10]);
    strcpy(ladrao.mesniver,&palavra[11]);
    strcpy(ladrao.dianiver,&palavra[12]);
    strcpy(ladrao.email,&palavra[13]);
    strcpy(ladrao.nomesacento,&palavra[14]);
    strcpy(ladrao.tratamento,&palavra[15]);
    strcpy(ladrao.profissao,&palavra[16]);
    strcpy(ladrao.nomecivil,&palavra[17]);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Tem o arquivo CSV original para fornecer ?

Comment: O arquivo está em txt. Seria um problema para o código?

Comment: Disponibilize o arquivo com as 514 linhas de entrada. Isso facilitaria bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pude perceber, a sua função `RecebeDados` tem a incumbência de ler uma linha do seu arquivo e retornar a estrutura `Cadastro` preenchida com o nome da variável `ladrao`.

Assim, tem dois erros que vc está cometendo:

- Abrindo a arquivo nessa função. Vc tem que abrir o arquivo antes e passar o *handle* para essa função
- Como vc está alterando a variável `ladrao`, ela tem que ser passada via ponteiro e não por valor, como vc está fazendo.

Assim, o seu programa deveria ser algo do tipo:

```
void RecebeDados(FILE *fp, Cadastro *ladrao){
     assert(fp != NULL);
     assert(ladrao != NULL);

     int i=0;

     ... /* continua igual ao seu programa até a linha abaixo */

     strcpy(ladrao->nomeparlamentar,&palavra[0]); /* note a notação de ponteiro aqui */
     ...
```

onde, os `assert` auxiliam na hora de fazer o debug do seu programa

Para usar essa função vc abre o arquivo e a chama, sucessivas vezes, até que leia todas as linhas

PS. Não se esqueça de fazer as verificações de erros, assim como se já se chegou no final do arquivo, quando estiver lendo-o

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma implementacao de um programa capaz de ler e processar linha a linha de um arquivo `CSV` com o formato que você especificou:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINHA_MAX_TAM            (1024 * 2)   /* 2 KBytes */

struct cadastro_s
{
    char * nomeparlamentar;
    char * partido;
    char * UF;
    char * estado;
    char * endereco;
    char * anexo;
    char * Econt;
    char * gabinete;
    char * Ecompl;
    char * telefone;
    char * fax;
    char * mesniver;
    char * dianiver;
    char * email;
    char * nomesacento;
    char * tratamento;
    char * profissao;
    char * nomecivil;
};


typedef struct cadastro_s cadastro_t;


char ** strsplit( const char * src, const char * delim )
{
    char * pbuf = NULL;
    char * ptok = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int srclen = 0;
    char ** pparr = NULL;

    srclen = strlen( src );

    pbuf = (char*) malloc( srclen + 1 );

    if( !pbuf )
        return NULL;

    strcpy( pbuf, src );

    ptok = strtok( pbuf, delim );

    while( ptok )
    {
        pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
        *(pparr + count) = strdup(ptok);

        count++;
        ptok = strtok( NULL, delim );
    }

    pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
    *(pparr + count) = NULL;

    free(pbuf);

    return pparr;
}


void strsplitfree( char ** strlist )
{
    int i = 0;

    while( strlist[i])
        free( strlist[i++] );

    free( strlist );
}


cadastro_t * parse_cadastro( char * linha )
{
    char ** pp = NULL;
    cadastro_t * cad = NULL;

    pp = strsplit( linha, ";" );

    cad = (cadastro_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(cadastro_t) );

    cad->nomeparlamentar = strdup(pp[0]);
    cad->partido = strdup(pp[1]);
    cad->UF = strdup(pp[2]);
    cad->estado = strdup(pp[3]);
    cad->endereco = strdup(pp[4]);
    cad->anexo = strdup(pp[5]);
    cad->Econt = strdup(pp[6]);
    cad->gabinete = strdup(pp[7]);
    cad->Ecompl = strdup(pp[8]);
    cad->telefone = strdup(pp[9]);
    cad->fax = strdup(pp[10]);
    cad->mesniver = strdup(pp[11]);
    cad->dianiver = strdup(pp[12]);
    cad->email = strdup(pp[13]);
    cad->nomesacento = strdup(pp[14]);
    cad->tratamento = strdup(pp[15]);
    cad->profissao = strdup(pp[16]);
    cad->nomecivil = strdup(pp[17]);

    strsplitfree( pp );

    return cad;
}


void destroy_cadastro( cadastro_t * cad )
{
    free(cad->nomeparlamentar);
    free(cad->partido);
    free(cad->UF);
    free(cad->estado);
    free(cad->endereco);
    free(cad->anexo);
    free(cad->Econt);
    free(cad->gabinete);
    free(cad->Ecompl);
    free(cad->telefone);
    free(cad->fax);
    free(cad->mesniver);
    free(cad->dianiver);
    free(cad->email);
    free(cad->nomesacento);
    free(cad->tratamento);
    free(cad->profissao);
    free(cad->nomecivil);

    free(cad);
}


void show_cadastro( cadastro_t * cad )
{
    printf( "[ CADASTRO ]\n" );
    printf( "   Nome Parlamentar: %s\n", cad->nomeparlamentar );
    printf( "   Partido: %s\n", cad->partido );
    printf( "   UF: %s\n", cad->UF );
    printf( "   Estado: %s\n", cad->estado );
    printf( "   Endereco: %s\n", cad->endereco );
    printf( "   Anexo: %s\n", cad->anexo );
    printf( "   Endereco: %s\n", cad->Econt );
    printf( "   Gabinete: %s\n", cad->gabinete );
    printf( "   Complemento: %s\n", cad->Ecompl );
    printf( "   Telefone: %s\n", cad->telefone );
    printf( "   Fax: %s\n", cad->fax );
    printf( "   Aniversario: %s/%s\n", cad->dianiver, cad->mesniver );
    printf( "   E-mail: %s\n", cad->email );
    printf( "   Nome: %s\n", cad->nomesacento );
    printf( "   Tratamento: %s\n", cad->tratamento );
    printf( "   Profissao: %s\n", cad->profissao );
    printf( "   Nome Civil: %s\n", cad->nomecivil );
    printf( "\n" );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char linha[ LINHA_MAX_TAM + 1 ];
    cadastro_t * c = NULL;
    FILE * fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    while( fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, fp ) )
    {
        c = parse_cadastro( linha );
        show_cadastro( c );
        destroy_cadastro( c );
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Arquivo de Teste `deputados.csv`:

```
ALEX CANZIANI;PTB;PR;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;842;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5842;3215-2842;06;11;dep.alexcanziani@camara.leg.br;ALEX CANZIANI;Exmo. Senhor Deputado;Registrador de Imóveis;ALEX CANZIANI SILVEIRA
ALEX MANENTE;PPS;SP;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;245;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5245;3215-2245;08;22;dep.alexmanente@camara.leg.br;ALEX MANENTE;Exmo. Senhor Deputado ;Bacharel  Em Direito;ALEX SPINELLI MANENTE
BRUNNY;PR;MG;T;Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo;4;, gabinete nº;260;Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900;3215-5260;3215-2260;08;21;dep.brunny@camara.leg.br;BRUNNY;Exma. Senhora Deputada;Superior Incompleto;BRUNIELE FERREIRA GOMES
```

Testando:

```
$ ./cadastro deputados.csv 
[ CADASTRO ]
    Nome Parlamentar: ALEX CANZIANI
    Partido: PTB
    UF: PR
    Estado: T
    Endereco: Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo
    Anexo: 4
    Endereco: , gabinete nº
    Gabinete: 842
    Complemento: Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900
    Telefone: 3215-5842
    Fax: 3215-2842
    Aniversario: 11/06
    E-mail: dep.alexcanziani@camara.leg.br
    Nome: ALEX CANZIANI
    Tratamento: Exmo. Senhor Deputado
    Profissao: Registrador de Imóveis
    Nome Civil: ALEX CANZIANI SILVEIRA


[ CADASTRO ]
    Nome Parlamentar: ALEX MANENTE
    Partido: PPS
    UF: SP
    Estado: T
    Endereco: Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo
    Anexo: 4
    Endereco: , gabinete nº
    Gabinete: 245
    Complemento: Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900
    Telefone: 3215-5245
    Fax: 3215-2245
    Aniversario: 22/08
    E-mail: dep.alexmanente@camara.leg.br
    Nome: ALEX MANENTE
    Tratamento: Exmo. Senhor Deputado 
    Profissao: Bacharel  Em Direito
    Nome Civil: ALEX SPINELLI MANENTE


[ CADASTRO ]
    Nome Parlamentar: BRUNNY
    Partido: PR
    UF: MG
    Estado: T
    Endereco: Câmara dos Deputados, Edifício Anexo
    Anexo: 4
    Endereco: , gabinete nº
    Gabinete: 260
    Complemento: Brasília - DF - CEP 70160-900
    Telefone: 3215-5260
    Fax: 3215-2260
    Aniversario: 21/08
    E-mail: dep.brunny@camara.leg.br
    Nome: BRUNNY
    Tratamento: Exma. Senhora Deputada
    Profissao: Superior Incompleto
    Nome Civil: BRUNIELE FERREIRA GOMES
```

Comment: Converti o deputados.txt para deputados.csv, para abrir o arquivo, é só trocar a extensão?

Comment: @hidantachi O nome do arquivo é passado como parametro na linha de comando.