# Duas strings partindo de uma, em C

Tags: c, string, funções

Olá, preciso um software que leia um nome completo, composto por um nome simples e um sobrenome, separados por “_” e os imprima separados.

O código deverá usar a seguinte função main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char nome[30];
    char * sobrenome;
    scanf("%s", nome);
    sobrenome = extraiSobrenome(nome);
    printf("Nome\n%s\nSobrenome\n%s\n",nome, sobrenome );
    return 0;
}
```

Tentei escrever a função `extraiSobrenome(nome);`, mas sem sucesso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extraiSobrenome(nome){
    int i=0, j=0, aux;
    char nova[30], michael[30];
    char sobrenome[30];
    strcpy(nova, nome);
    for(i=0;i<(int)strlen(nova);i++){
        if(nova[i]==95){
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    aux=i;
    while(i<strlen(nova)){
        sobrenome[j]=nova[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    sobrenome[strlen(nova)-aux] = '\0';

    return sobrenome;
}

int main(){
    char nome[30];
    char * sobrenome;
    scanf("%s", nome);
    sobrenome = extraiSobrenome(nome);
    printf("Nome\n%s\nSobrenome\n%s\n", nome, sobrenome );
    return 0;
}
```

O problema não é apenas conseguir separar o sobrenome, mas alterar o nome também, podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou declarar o retorno da função `extraiSobrenome`. Que no caso seria um ponteiro de caracter, ou `char*`.

Note que você precisa alterar a variável `nome` original, caso contrário não terá sucesso ao imprimir `nome` separadamente.

Você poderia usar a função da biblioteca padrão `strtok` para fazer essa divisão a cada `_`, mas creio que aqui o interesse não seja em usar a biblioteca padrão mas sim em treinar escrita de algoritmos em C.

Uma versão adequada de `extraiSobrenome` sem usar a biblioteca padrão:

```
char *extraiSobrenome(char *nome_com_sobrenome) {
  char *fim_nome = nome_com_sobrenome;
  while (*fim_nome != '_' && *fim_nome != '\0') {
    fim_nome++;
  }
  if (*fim_nome == '\0') {
    // oops, fim da palavra antes de achar o delimitador '_', devo retornar nulo ou um sobrenome vazio?
    return fim_nome; // estou retornando um sobrenome vazio para evitar falhas de segmentação
  }
  // se não caiu no 'if' anterior, então garanto que achou um '_'
  * fim_nome = '\0'; // estou marcando o fim do nome, substituindo o '_' pelo caracter nulo, portanto indicando que a string acabou
  return fim_nome +1; // usando aritmética de ponteiros para indicar que o sobrenome começa na próxima letra
}
```

Alguns outros pontos que gostaria de levantar sobre seu código:

- você comparou um caracter com 95; ok, no final das contas letras são números com zeros e uns, mas o que é 95?
  Por que não comparar diretamente com `'_'`? Muito mais expressiva essa comparação e todo mundo que ler seu código e que não saiba a tabela ASCII decorada vai entender essa versão da comparação
- você retornou um vetor criado internamente na função, e isso não é bacana...
  Essas variáveis são guardadas na pilha, e elas só fazem sentido dentro do contexto da execução da função propriamente dita; quando ela retorna, não há mais como garantir o significado do resto da pilha da última chamada... e esse código é válido sintaticamente porque internamente o C trabalha apenas com o endereço do vetor, então você está retornando um endereço de um valor que está na pilha que pode ser sobrescrito a qualquer momento.

Leia mais sobre pilha, *heap*, escopo de variável... vou listar algumas sugestões de leituras:

- [O que são e onde estão o "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/64969)
- [Como funciona a C99 em relação à C90 para declaração de variáveis no meio do código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48231/64969)
- [Passando por referência em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72706/64969)
- [Como funciona o tempo de vida de variáveis estáticas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233805/64969)
- [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/64969)
- [Alocação de objetos e ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/64969)
- nessa resposta o @Maniero trata da terminologia elegantemente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215832/64969
- [Por que pode passar um vetor de chjar para o scanf como endereço ou a variável direto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251918/64969)

Sobre `strtok`:

- [Separar pequenas strings de uma string gigante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236817/64969); particularmente gosto muito da resposta que o @Isac deu

Answer (score -2):

O que você acha de depois de gravar o primeiro nome você acrescentar um espaço assim:

```
strcat(nome, " ");
```

Comment: Usar `strcat` simplesmente não tem como atender ao problema em questão.

Comment: Achei que você só quisesse separar as duas strings...

Comment: Com essa intenção de "separar duas strings" `strcat` também não vai ajudar em nada

Comment: #include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  


int main()  
{  
   char nome[10];  
   char sobrenome[10];  
   
   printf("Informe nome: ");  
   gets(nome);  
   strcat(nome, " ");  
  
   printf("\nInforme sobrenome: ");  
   gets(sobrenome);  
   strcat(nome, sobrenome);  
  
   printf("%s", nome);  
  
  
    return 0;  
}

Comment: Você leu que o nome e o sobrenome são dados divididos por um '_'? Então, não, não vão ser dadas duas leituras... Note também que a impressão é com nome e sobrenome separados, a intenção não é juntar

Comment: hummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm ta bem, então boa sorte aí!!!